# width is bounded when applying SLD in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I applied a SLD style to color a road network in Geoserver (see the picture, before the styling, all lines are in the same color). Before the styling, I can query the WMS layer with arbitrary width and height values. But after the styling, I cannot get the right picture if I increase width to certain number.

For example, consider the following query to WMS

http://"hostname"/geoserver/Workspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Lines&styles=&bbox=-91.44184599959314,36.99574399968581,-87.52404399962063,42.508301999999986&**width=410**&height=512&srs=EPSG:4269&format=image%2Fpng

Before applying the color style, I can set the width value to any number;

After applying the color style, I can only set width no larger than 410. I do not understand why the styling matters.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: check the log - you may be running out of memory if it is a complex style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it's stupid to answer my own question. But in case anyone runs into the same problem in future.

The above problem occurs because the memory needed for a rendering exceeds the memory limit for a WMS layer, which can be configured via the web interface. Please see [enter link description here](http://opengeo.org/publications/geoserver-production/).